# Cassandra nodetool cfstats show 'percentage repaired=0' for 'index table'?

Tags: cassandra

I create secondary index on several tables. Then I ran nodetool -pr on every nodes in the cluster successfully. But when I check table status using nodetool cfstats, finding that outputs information about index table (supposed be hidden). Some index table are 100% repaired, some are 0%.
My question is:

1. does 'percentage repaired' mean anything to index table?
2. does 'percentage repaired less than 100%' means the table are not repaired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run full repairs, you'll never see the 'Percent repaired' change, this is only to track incremental repairs, so less than 100% doesn't always mean it isn't repaired, it could be that full repairs were used instead of incremental.

As for the index, repair only applies to the underlying table, so a repair of the table would also rebuild index inconsistencies.  If you need to repair just an index, then I don't believe rebuild_index affects the Percent repaired, so I'd reference the base table the index is built on.

Comment: Thanks Paul. So 'repair -pr' is actually a full repair, right? Then is there any indicator that tells the completion of full repair, just like percent repaired for incremental repairs?

Comment: Correct, 'repair -pr' is a full repair, you'll just need to run it on all nodes in the ring one-at-a-time.  The best way to monitor this is by monitoring Cassandra's system/debug.log, it will give you a repair ID when it's kicked off, and you can grep the log for it to ensure you know it reached 100%

Comment: Hi Paul, I found that 'Percent repaired' could change even there are no data write/update. Do you have any idea why it happens? You can see this link for more detail  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77451235/cassandra-percent-repaired-changes-even-no-data-write-update

Comment: it's possible some amount of data was held in memtables and flushed to disk sometime after the repair