# Cassandra - Percent repaired changes even no data write/update?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I created a scheduler job on **2am** repairing cass cluster. It runs repair -pr on each node. And after repair, it will use nodetool tablestats checking each table's 'Percent repaired' if it's 100%. Then at **6am**, it will again nodetool tablestats checking 'Percent repaired'.

So I found after repair at 2am, all tables will show 'Percent repair:100%'.
Then at 6am, the metric drop under 100% on one or two tables.

Between 2am and 6am, there were **no data write or update at all**.

Could someone explain this phenomenon?